# Storing clicks and impressions (for banners) in a Mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am new to Mongodb and I have a SQL background.

So my app records the number of clicks and impressions for banners and I have decided to store all this into a single document per banner which looks like this:

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId('534b45b9b6d966a8010002323'),
  "active": true,
  "banner_end": ISODate("2015-06-05T23:59:59.0Z"),
  "banner_name": "Cool banner",
  "banner_position": "bottom",
  "banner_url": "http:\/\/www.google.com",
  "banner_image":"http:\/\/www.google.com/pic.jpg",
  "click_details": [
    {
      "date": ISODate("2014-04-14T02:29:22.961Z"),
      "ip": "::1"
    }
  ],
  "clicks": NumberInt(1),
  "impression_details": [
    {
      "date": ISODate("2014-04-14T02:28:41.353Z"),
      "ip": "::1"
    },
    {
      "date": ISODate("2014-04-14T02:28:53.52Z"),
      "ip": "::1"
    }
  ],
  "impressions": NumberInt(2)
}
```

Obviously, as time goes by, the array of click_details and impression_details will increase (especially the impressions). I was wondering if I am doing this correctly? Or should I store the click_details and impression_detail onto a separate collection?

I will need click_detail and impression_detail later to plot graphs.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this approach and moreover the sub-document has a limit of 16 MB in Mongo which will store many records for you.

Can you also highlight the number of users which you get on your site and expected number of impressions / clicks for a banner.

P.S. You can save lot of space by aliasing your columns in JSON, e.g. banner_name could be written as bn_nm and so on.